# iOS Button Custom Image bounds

Tags: ios, button

I have multiple buttons in the shape of an octagon, and they are all right next to each other. Sharing edges. However, when i import these custom images for a button, the bounds of the custom shape is a square. Therefore, part of one of the octagon is overlapping the one right next to this. Not the actual octagon but the transform tool/modifer button bounds. Thus part of the button, though it is hidden, is overlapping another button. How do i modify the button to only take shape to the bounds of the custom shape?

Answer (score 0):

subclass `UIButton` and override `-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. check if the point is inside your octagon shape and return YES in that case, otherwise NO. Then the buttons will technically still be overlapping but only consume touch events inside your shape.